# Access public Google Calendar from my application

Tags: google-calendar-api

I would like to ask you a question about google calendar. I have connected public google calendar from one account. If I'm logged as same user in browser everything is OK, but I would like to do that same for users who will be listing in event in my application. This time it's working only like someone has to logged with credentials from account where is the calendar but I would like to do that public for users (without authorization).

Thanks a lot for any answer,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a [Google API Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts). This will allow your application to use the Google Calendar API without requiring login of any sort on the front-end (no OAuth or other user-required auth).